# SQLite Database query function not replacing the ? with selection args

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

i have a get function in my database class to get a specific line from the DB.

```
 public Line getLine(String date){
    SQLiteDatabase sql = db.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    Line line = new Line();
    try{
        cursor = sql.query(Db_name,null,DATE_COL+"=?",new String[] {date},null,null,null);
        line = new Line(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3).equals("YES"));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.getCause();
    }
    finally {
        if (sql.isOpen())
            sql.close();
    }
    return line;
}`
```

however when i run it, the cursor is not getting the right query, when debbuging it looks like this:

> SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM a28a9a2015 WHERE date_col=?

so it kept the ? and did not put the date string in there.. 
i've tried something like -

```
 cursor = sql.query(Db_name,null,DATE_COL+"="+date,null,null,null,null);
```

OR

```
 cursor = sql.query(Db_name,null,DATE_COL+"= '"+date+"',null,null,null,null);
```

with same result.

any pointers?

Comment: whenever in doubts use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move cursor to first position

```
cursor = sql.query(Db_name,null,DATE_COL+"=?",new String[] {date},null,null,null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     // TODO
}
```

Otherwise your cursor is in position -1 and cannot get any data. Symbol "?" is replacing inside request to sqlite so in cursor you'll see "?".